# FLEX: Dynamically accessing multiple datagrids by passing caller object ids to a function

Tags: php, apache-flex, data-binding, datagrid, arraycollection

**SOLVED**

I have a Flex/PHP app I'm working on.

I have a single ArrayCollection for a data source, but have 8 datagrids (named dg1 through dg8).  I use 8 datagrids for logical presentation (4 years of college, 2 semesters per year).  I have a column with "X" (for "delete this record") that goes to a function when clicked.

What I'd like to do is pass the datagrid id (such as "dg1") and the data provider {syllabus.freshFall} to a function.  I've been trying my hardest to find how I do this, but have only found examples of single datagrids (which look pretty easy) and referring to a single fixed datagrid like this:

```
course_id=dg1.selectedItem.course_ID;
syllabus.freshFall.removeItemAt(dg1.selectedIndex);
```

I want to make this something like this:

```
course_id=**whateverDataGrid**.selectedItem.course_ID;
**whateverDataProvider**.removeItemAt(**whateverDataGrid**.selectedIndex);
```

**NOW I need help passing my c_id variable to my HTTPService.**

Thanks for ALL your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PARTIAL ANSWER:**

with help from [Adobe LiveDocs for Flex 3](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/index.html?content=usingas_3.html)

```
<mx:LinkButton label="X" click="outerDocument.itemClickEvent('1',event)"/>


public function itemClickEvent(id:String, event:MouseEvent):void {
        var mydp:Object;
        switch(int(id))
        {
            case 1:
                mydp=syllubus.freshFall;
                break;
                               .
                               .
                            case 8:
                mydp=syllubus.seniorSpring;

            default:
                trace("Out of range");
                break;
        }
        id = "dg" + id;
        c_id=this[id].selectedItem.course_ID;
        mydp.removeItemAt(this[id].selectedIndex);  //superficial datagrid delete
```

I would still like to make the data provider more of a variable, just to be complete.  I tried several different approaches and the case statements were the closest to what I wanted and **it worked** for now.

Figured out passing my c_id variable from my function to my HTTPService.  Not exactly as straight-forward as I would have hoped...

Build a variable in the type of Object
Add an element to the object of the name of your variable you want to pass
Add a value for the variable.
Pass the

It looks like this:

```
function blah (var:int, ...rest):void {

code...

code...

c_id= *whatever*;
params["cid"] = c_id;
update.send(params);  (where "update" is the HttpService id)
}

.
.
.
.

<mx:HTTPService 
    id="update"     
    url="http://localhost/myFile.php" 
    method="POST"  
    etc...>
 <mx:request>
   <xmlstring>{XMLString}</xmlstring>   (this xml string is generated elsewhere)
   <cid>c_id</cid>
 </mx:request>
</mx:HTTPService>
```

Hope this helps someone else.  It's been a bit of a pain to piece this all together.